# Nerdctl compose and devices

Tags: containerd, nerdctl

Is it possible to use host device (like /dev/ttyUSB0) in container using nerdctl compose?

I want to use as normal docker-compose.yaml with device gpoup like in docker system.

I'm using nerdctl 1.5.0 version with containerd daemon